# Exact sequence of topological groups induces exact sequence on the fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, fundamental-groups, exact-sequence

I think it’s a general result, but if you like you can assume compact Lie Groups.

Here is the situation:

We have a exact sequence of path connected topological groups

$$ 1 \rightarrow  A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 1$$

Name the continuous homomorphisms $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. I would like to know if the following sequence is exact:

$$ 1 \rightarrow \pi_1(A) \rightarrow \pi_1(B) \rightarrow \pi_1(C) \rightarrow 1$$

With the induced maps $f_*$ and $g_*$.

I already proved $\operatorname{Im} f_* \subset \ker g_*$, but I can’t conclude the other inclusion. If you have any other suggestion to conclude it I would be very happy.

Remark: In general it’s not true that a injective map implies that the induced map on the fundamental group is injective. Example: inclusion of $\mathbb{S}^1$ in $\mathbb{B}^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am supposing $A$, $B$ and $C$ as compact connected Lie Groups.

Since

$$1\longrightarrow A \xrightarrow{\ \ f \ \ }B \xrightarrow{\ g \ }C\longrightarrow 1,$$
is exact, $f$ is an injection. Using that $A$ is a compact Lie group one can conclude that $f(A)$ is a closed subgroup of $B$, and therefore $f$ is an embedding by Cartan's theorem which shows us that $f(A)$ is an embedded submanifold of $B$. Note that $f(A)=\text{Ker}(g)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(A)$ is a normal subgroup of $B$. Moreover, $C\cong B/\text{Ker(g)} = B/\text{Im}(f),$ by the map $\tilde{g}: B/\text{Im}(f) \to C$, $\tilde g(b+\text{Im}(f)) = g(b)$. Since $f(A)$ is closed then   $B/\text{Im}(f)$ is also a Lie group.

And then, we have the comutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>>>A @>f>> B @>g>> C@>>> 1\\
  @.      @VV{f}V @VV{\text{Id}}V  @VV{\tilde{g}^{-1}}V @.\\
1@>>> f(A) @>\iota>> B @>\pi>> B/f(A)@>>>1
\end{CD}.$$

It is clear that the following induced diagram is also commutative

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>>>\pi_1(A) @>f_*>> \pi_1(B) @>g_*>> \pi_1(C)@>>> 1\\
  @.      @VV{f_*}V @VV{\text{Id}_*}V  @VV{\tilde{g}^{-1}_*}V @.\\
1@>>> \pi_1(f(A)) @>\iota_*>> \pi_1(B) @>\pi_*>> \pi_1(B/f(A))@>>>1
\end{CD} ,$$

Thus it is enough to prove that the last line of the above diagram is an exact sequence ($f_*$, $\text{Id}_*$ and $\tilde{g}^{-1}_*$ are isomorphisms).

But this is obvious since $f(A) \to B \to B/f(A)$ is a fibration and from the [long exact sequence of fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration)

$$\ldots\to \pi_n(f(A))\to \pi_n(B)\to \pi_n(B/\text{Im}(A))\to\ldots\to \pi_2(B/\text{Im}(A))\to \pi_1(f(A))\to \pi_1(B)\to \pi_1(B/\text{Im}(A))\to {1}, $$
since [$\pi_2(B/\text{Im}(f)) =1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups), because $B/\text{Im}(f)$ is a Lie group we have proved the result.

**Remark:** We have supposed $A$, $B$ and $C$ as Lie groups just to be able to conclude that $\pi_2(B/\text{Im}(f))$ is trivial.

**EDIT:** As Aloizio Macedo pointed out in the comment section, it is also important to suppose $A$, $B$ and $C$ Lie groups in order to guarantee that we have a fibration.

Comment: Regarding your remark: As far as I'm aware, you also use that they are compact Lie groups in order to guarantee that you have a fibration.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo maybe I am missing something. But as far as I remember this is valid for topological groups (maybe you need to suppose $T_2$ as well) if the group you are quocienting is compact. But I will make this observation. This is not my main area of research. So I really think that you are right.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Do you know if this result (the question made by the OP) is true in general? This question really made me very curious. The only way managed to solve it was by assuming Lie groups and using very deep results from the Lie Group theory. I confess that I am not 100% satisfied with my answer.

Comment: I suspect the result in the OP isn't true in general, but I don't know examples. The first idea would be to search for a path-connected topological group for which $\pi_2 \neq 0$. To be honest, I don't know much examples of non-Lie path-connected topological groups. (To be more honest, I don't know any off the top of my head other than topological vector spaces, say, which are arguably "disguised" Lie groups.) Finding a suitable example may be ugly. Of course, I'd like to be proven wrong and for it to be simple.

Comment: The results from Lie Group theory you mention are somewhat standard and seem to be needed, so you are not really using much heavy machinery to be unsatisfied about. : ) I'd say that this was probably the way that the person who made the exercise was thinking about.

Comment: The most general hypotheses which I am reasonably certain that the result holds are: all path-connected topological groups, and $A$ a closed subgroup which is also a Lie group on its own right. But then the amount of results being used would probably be increased considerably. (For instance, the proof I know that $\pi_2(G) =0$ when $G$ is not compact uses that every Lie group is homotopy equivalent to a compact one, which AFAIK is deep.)